# SQL Server: select the first character that is not a digit 0-9 or /

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, text

I have a table called `Person`, and a `NVarChar` column called `Notes`.

The `Notes` column has a lot of text in it, but always begins with a number of some kind, with `/`'s inserted throughout.

For example:

```
1/23 some text
45/678/9%*&^%$#@
02/468/ some other text
```

I need to select the first character position that isn't a digit or `/`.
I don't care whether the position is 0-based or 1-based; I can accommodate that after the fact.

In this example, if I'm using 1-based character positions, the selection should produce the following:

```
5
9
8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you're looking for an index that matches some sort of pattern, say a pattern index. If we're whimsical, we might abbreviate it to [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql).

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9/]%', Notes)
FROM Person
```

Comment: Oh cool, I've never seen that keyword before. Regarding the syntax, if I wanted to add `-` to the the pattern as well, in addition to the `/`, how would I notate that?

Comment: Tack it on at the start or the end: `[^0-9/-]`. The `-` is only special if it could form some valid range between two other characters. Some more examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-character-s-to-match-transact-sql), though the documentation is sparse.